# Stack Implementation

Tags: c++, stack

I would like comments on my implementation of a stack:

```
template <class T>
class Stack {
 public:
        void pop(T& element);
        void push(const T& element); 
 Stack();

 private:
         int elementCount_;
         int stackTop_;
  static const int  MAX_ELEMS = 10;
  T elementArray_[MAX_ELEMS]; 
};

template <class T>
Stack<T>::Stack() :
elementCount_(0),stackTop_(-1)
{
}

template <class T>
void Stack<T>::push(const T& element)
{
 if (stackTop_ == MAX_ELEMS-1){
            std::cout << "Stack is full" << "\n" ;
            return;    
 }
        elementArray_[++stackTop_] = element;
 elementCount_++;
}

template <class T>
void Stack<T>::pop(T& element)
{
    if (stackTop_ == -1){
     std::cout << "Stack is empty" << "\n";
     return;
    }
    elementCount_--;
    element =  elementArray_[stackTop_--];
}
```

Comment: You don't provide a way to get the top element.  That makes the stack less than useful; any pushes and pops are basically busywork.

Comment: I return it in pop via argument, but I can see why looking at the top without pop would be useful. Thanks

Comment: Ahh.  I missed the argument to `pop`, actually; i just saw that it returned `void`.

Comment: In C++ standard library the pop does not return a value (it just removes the top item). As a consequence there is call called top() that gives you a reference to the top value. See: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4892324/14065 for a discussion on the reasons. As a result I would also argue you should follow the standard C++ idiom and provide a `top()` method and make `pop()` not return a value.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here are some things that may help you improve your code.

### Throw errors rather than printing error messages

The user of your code may be creating a GUI with no command line available and will not appreciate having your code printing instead of indicating an error to the calling code.  The two ways that C++ programs generally signal an error are either by throwing an exception (if the circumstance really is exceptional) or by returning a value that indicates an error.

### Use consistent formatting

The code as posted has inconsistent indentation which makes it hard to read and understand. Pick a style and apply it consistently.

### Consider adding functionality

Since this is a fixed-size rather than a dynamically sized stack, it would make sense to either allow the user to specify that size (as perhaps with a default parameter for the constructor) and to query it.  Also, consider adding functions such as `isFull()` and `isEmpty()`.

Comment: For a fixed size stack I'd go even further and make the capacity parameter *required*.

Answer (score 5):

- As it stands, if the stack is empty, `pop` doesn't alter `element`, and doesn't let the code know that it failed.  So the code using the stack thinks it popped whatever `element` was before the operation.  Same with `push` if the stack is full; the code has no way of knowing that it didn't *really* just push an element.

  You should throw an exception if an operation fails.  (Alternatively, you could return `false`.  But C++ has exceptions, and error codes are too easy to ignore.)
- I'm not a fan of returning by reference without good reason.  "Good reason" includes already returning a value (which you don't).
- `stackTop_` and `elementCount_` are (at least currently) redundant.  You never alter one without altering the other the same way, so `elementCount_` is always equal to `stackTop_ + 1`.  I'd recommend eliminating `elementCount_` and calculating it from `stackTop_`, or vice versa.

  Or, even better, change things so that `stackTop_` *is* the element count -- that is, it is always the index of the next element to be pushed.  That would simplify things quite a bit, actually, by making the preconditions feel less rickety.

  ```
  template <class T>
  void Stack<T>::push(const T& element) {
      // note how we're not checking against MAX_ELEMS-1 anymore.
      // since the stack top is the element count, now it's just
      // "if the stack already has MAX_ELEMS elements".
      if (stackTop_ == MAX_ELEMS) {
          throw std::runtime_error("Stack is full");
      }

      elementArray_[stackTop_++] = element;
  }

  template <class T>
  void Stack<T>::pop(T& element) {
      // same here. Turns "if the next index is -1" into "if there are 0 elements".
      if (stackTop_ == 0) {
          throw std::runtime_error("Stack is empty");
      }

      element = elementArray_[--stackTop_];
  }
  ```
- Just so it's said, elements aren't being disposed of once they're popped.  This isn't a big deal with built-in types...but for non-trivial types, it could lead to things being held onto longer than they should be.  (A `Stack<std::string>`, for example, would hold on to copies of each string pushed until you pop it *and* push something else to overwrite it, or until the stack is destroyed -- whichever comes first.)